# Post of NSNotificationCenter causing "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, exc-bad-access, nsnotificationcenter

A `UIViewController` adds itself to the default center:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(editFood)
 name:@"editFood"
 object:nil];
```

Then a `UITableView` delegate NSObject posts a `NSNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:@"editFood"
 object:self];
```

During run time it get a **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** exception.

Is the `defaultCenter` getting released somewhere? The same concept works when I post a notification to a UIViewController from a UIViewController, but that shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: Where exactly is it crashing?

Comment: adding `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]` to `-(void)dealloc{}` method in your Scene will probably solve this problem for you. It worked for me; I was having the same problem you were. Good luck!

Answer (score 131):

One of your subscribers has been deallocated.  Make sure to call `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]` in your dealloc (if not sooner).

Comment: Thanks, I just realized my mistake (After looking at this and researching for four hours). The object I was attempting to reference after the call had been released. The debugger just made it look like that's where the EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception was being thrown.

Comment: @Paul: The Zombies instrument is really helpful in debugging this kind of problem.

Comment: @Sven Thanks, I appreciate it. I actually tried using that once, and couldn't figure out how. I added an environment variable in the project plist, but that wouldn't work.

Comment: i'm releasing that object after notification called i got EXC_BAD_ACCESS how can i solve that?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS is not an exception, it's invalid memory access

Answer (score 11):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` can happen even after verifying dealloc exists like so:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]
}
```

The above will solve the problem most of the time, but apparently my cause was that I was indirectly adding the observer with a `selector:` set to `nil` as follows:

```
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self
                                         selector:nil
                                             name:notificationName
                                           object:nil];
```

...so when I posted something with that `notificationName`, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` occurred.

The solution was to send a selector that actually points to something.

Comment: Yup, just found this myself, I had put `NULL` as the selector intending it to be temporary, like oh let me go create that method, then I forgot to go update the selector param later (DOH) and yep, EXC_BAD_ACCESS result.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in **Swift**. The problem was the function target had a `closure` parameter with default value:

```
@objc func performFoo(completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
   ...
}
```

After I replace the `closure` parameter with a `Notification` parameter, it worked:

```
@objc func performFoo(notification: Notification) {
    ...
}
```

I had to make some refactor to make it works in a right way.

Comment: Yes, the documentation for `NotificationCenter addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)` does state: *"The method that aSelector specifies must have one and only one argument (an instance of NSNotification)."*.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting this error and using async/await, be sure to check if this other issue might not be the cause https://stackoverflow.com/a/76066999/2828729

tl;dr: at the time of writing `@objc` selectors and `async` methods don't go well together

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of async/await, be also careful for your selectors to not have the `async` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur with the wrong method header. I just got the error by not accepting an object when the notification was sending an object.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: MyNotification.name, object: self)
```

Will work with:

```
@objc func myFunction(_ sender: AnyObject) {}
```

But not with

```
@objc func myFunction() {}
```

NOTE: This was edited to have the functions not be "async throws" which will cause a sporadic crash.

Comment: Yes, the documentation for `NotificationCenter addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)` does state: *"The method that aSelector specifies must have one and only one argument (an instance of NSNotification)."*. And I'm not sure using an `async throws` method is a good idea for a function marked with `@objc`. See the more recent answers about that.

Comment: You are right! This causes an intermittent crash. I had to change this from being async throws. Its deceptive because it doesn't crash every time.