# UIDevice setOrientation:animated: causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, uikit, exc-bad-access, uidevice

I have a crash log submitted to iTunes. I am not sure how to recreate the issue, so it is difficult for me to trouble shoot.

[UIDevice setOrientation:animated:] is causing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on iOS 6.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the pertinent part of the crash log:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x347d9692 objc_msgSend_stret + 18
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3641f034 _CFXNotificationPost
2   Foundation                      0x33ee1d8c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]
3   UIKit                           0x377a5c68 -[UIDevice setOrientation:animated:]
4   UIKit                           0x377a03de -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:]
5   UIKit                           0x3779f6d0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
6   UIKit                           0x3779f11e _UIApplicationHandleEvent
7   GraphicsServices                0x369525a0 _PurpleEventCallback
8   GraphicsServices                0x369521ce PurpleEventCallback
9   CoreFoundation                  0x364a3170     __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
10  CoreFoundation                  0x364a3112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1
11  CoreFoundation                  0x364a1f94 __CFRunLoopRun
12  CoreFoundation                  0x36414eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
13  CoreFoundation                  0x36414d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode
14  GraphicsServices                0x369512e6 GSEventRunModal
15  UIKit                           0x377f32fc UIApplicationMain
16  MyApp                       0x0001234a main + 70
17  MyApp                       0x000122fc start + 36
```

Comment: It is not causing it, whatever you are doing to respond to it is causing it.  Look over what you are doing in methods that respond to device orientation changes.

Comment: That makes sense, but darn, that doesn't narrow it down much. Most objects I have handle rotation events...

Comment: It's likely only "device" orientation changes (face up, face down, etc), not "interface" orientation changes (portrait, landscape) but I am not sure

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it's a live object that messes up.
I'd say that you forgot to unregister an observer and it got deallocated but is still scheduled to get notifications -- look at any class that subscribes to this particular notification and see if add/removes are balanced

Comment: I would agree, but I checked every object that uses a notification and I am removing the notification in all the objects in dealloc. That said, in some of the dealloc methods, I was not removing the notifcation first; I was removing it after releasing some objects. I suppose there is a very slight possibility that could have caused it, so I moved the de-notification to the top of each dealloc method.

Comment: Try running it in instruments with zombies enabled if it still occurs.

Comment: See the original post; I am unable to recreate the issue. I only have a crash log that was submitted to iTunes to work with.

Comment: @downvoter why? my answer fits to the crash report shown

Comment: Stop downvoting other people just because you don't like the answer or it doesn't solve the problem 100 %. As long its not totally offtopic it helps to solve problems.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Daij-Djan already mentioned, it can't be the orientation change itself, because there is still a post of `NSNotification` and than the app is crashing. Have again a look at the classes you have added `NSNotificationCenter` to, maybe there is no problem on unregistering but on registering like the [post I found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26333917/1141395)